# Obtaining embedding from geodesic

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, metric-geometry

Suppose $M$ is an embedded sub-manifold of $D$-dimensional Euclidean space $E^D$, with embedding $\phi:M \hookrightarrow E^D$.

And suppose I know the induced Riemmanian-metric $g$ on $M$, which depends by construction on $\phi$ (which so happens that I don't explicitly know).

Can I express $\phi$ in terms of $g$ (closed form or as a PDE maybe?).

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible in general. A cylinder $S^1 \times \mathbb{R} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}^3$ is locally isometric to a flat plane $\mathbb{R}^2 \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}^3$. So one can find a small piece of the cylinder and of the flat plane which are isometric to each other.

But their embeddings are quite different, for example the extrinsic curvatures on the cylinder can be nonzero, but on the flat plane are zero.

Comment: I'm not convinced this is true, the cylinder is locally diffeomorphic but not locally isometric to Euclidean Space; at best the Riemmanian metric is locally equivalent but I don't believe that it is an isometry.

Comment: I agree, for example let $x:=(\theta_1,1)$ and $y:=(\theta_2,1)$ be points on $S^1\times \mathbb{R}$ *(with the product Riemmanian metric which is the induced metric in this case).*  The geodesic connecting those points is an arc length (because of product metric structure) and therefore is of length $\operatorname{L}(\gamma_{[x,y]})=(\frac{2\pi}{|\theta_2-\theta_1|}^2+(1-1)^2)^{1/2}>|(cos(\theta_1),sin(\theta_1))-(cos(\theta_2),sin(\theta_2))|_{l^2}$, which is the Euclidean distance... so no.

Comment: ^ I agree that is what I thought

Comment: @CSA: Mosher is right, of course. In your example you are confusing the intrinsic Riemannian metric and its distance function and the restriction of the extrinsic distance function. What your calculation shows is that they are different. What Lee is saying is that the induced Riemannian metric on the cylinder is flat, which is of course true, since this metric is isometric to the product Riemannian metric on the product of $S^1$ and $R$.

Comment: @MrLibraryGuy: See my comment about where I ping CSA.